# how to get the intent from the (add)proximityalert into a broadcastreceiver?

Tags: java, android, methods, alert, proximity

how to get the intent from the (add)proximityalert into a broadcastreceiver? 
and how to make the onreceive method to work?

```
Intent locationNotific = new Intent("SendProximityIntent");
    locationNotific.putExtra("RowID", id);
    sendBroadcast(locationNotific);
    PendingIntent lPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, locationNotific, 0);

       IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter("SendProximityIntent"); 

       registerReceiver(new ProximityIntentReceiver(), filter);


    lm.addProximityAlert((double) locationAlertGeoP.getLatitudeE6(),(double) locationAlertGeoP.getLongitudeE6(), (float) 999999999,(long) 100000,lPendingIntent);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how to get the intent from the (add)proximityalert into a broadcastreceiver?

Use `getBroadcast()` instead of `getActivity()` and supply an `Intent` identifying a manifest-registered `BroadcastReceiver`.